# Android - sending url from from activity 1 to activity 2 with webView

Tags: java, android, mobile, webview

I've got my project [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/Vb48W/Stackoverflow.zip) if someone would like to see.

So I want to click image on activity1(which is going to hold link) and then go to second activity with a webview which will open that link. How do I do that?
Here is my current code for that, but it crashes the app when I click on image:

```
//Activity1.java

 public void onClick(View view)
    {       
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);

        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        bundle.putString("urlString", url);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(act2);
    }
```

activity2.java:

```
//Activity2.java

   //OnCreate
    String url = super.getIntent().getExtras().getString("urlString");
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

  private void load(String url)
  {
      mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      mWebView.loadUrl(url);
  }
```

Feel free to check out the whole code [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/Vb48W/Stackoverflow.zip)
And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {       

            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("urlString", "http://www.google.com");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("urlString");
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Add WebView Client on Webview

Comment: Alright, I will. Its for the navigation so the app doesnt open web browser - right?